# Big-oh proof on differentiable functions

Tags: algorithm, big-o, calculus

In the following question, suppose that f, g : R → R are differentiable and
strictly increasing (f'(x) > 0 and g'(x) > 0 for all x). Prove the following statement or provide a counter example: Is f(x) = O(g(x)) if and only if f'(x) = O(g'(x))?

I understand the big-oh limit definition, and it makes sense that the above would hold true given my basic knowledge of calculus, but I am not sure how to write a sound proof mathematically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange

Comment: "If an only if" has two directions.  It's true that **f'(x) in O(g'(x)) => f(x) in O(g(x))**, but not true that **f(x) in O(g(x)) => f'(x) in O(g'(x))**.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Well, i think the first part of your statement is wrong. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Yola if you like, but I think allowing g(x) to be negative is just weaseling around the intent of restricting g'(x)>0

Answer (score 0):

The counterexample would be to put `g(x) = 0` and `f(x) = 1`. Both derivatives are zeros, so `f'(x) = O(g'(x))` holds, but that's not true that `1 = O(0)`.

EDIT: Ok, i missed condition on non-zero derivatives, but still there is a counterexample. And the idea is the same - make `g(x)` infinitely close to zero.

Consider [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). Let's put `g(x) = erf(x) - 1` and `f(x) = erf(x)`. `g(x)` will get closer to zero with `x` getting bigger, so it is not possible to find appropriate constant to exceed `f(x)`. So, though `f'(x) = O(g'(x))` (actually, `f'(x) = g'(x)`) that's not true that `f(x) = O(g(x))`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if `f'(x) = g'(x)` then `f'(x) = O(g'(x))` is a false statement. `f = O(g)` means that no matter what constant we use for `f`, there is a point `x` starting at which `C*f(x) < g(x)`. So if `f'(x) = g'(x)` then `2f'(x) > g'(x)` for **every** x, which effectively means that `f'` is not `O(g')`.

Comment: It's not false, you can look up definition here [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition). There is no strict inequality.